# After changing directory "yo" command not executing in batch file through command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, yeoman

I have a batch file,

it will open the command prompt and change the directory.

After changing it has to execute yo command, but after changing the directory it's not executing yo command,

Here is my batch file

```
 @echo off 
cmd.exe /K  "cd D:/Jhipster/myapp"  && C:  yo jhipster:import-jdl D:/Jhipster/mindmaple/City.jh
```

Comment: if you manually run the yo command above in that dir, what do you see?

Comment: `&& C:  yo` What is that `C:` supposed to do there?

Comment: Always use `\ `as path separator in `CMD`!

Answer (score 0):

You must place the `yo` command inside the double quotes:

```
cmd.exe /K  "cd D:/Jhipster/myapp  && C:yo jhipster:import-jdl D:/Jhipster/mindmaple/City.jh"
```

(There were white spaces between `C:` and `yo` in your command, I presumed that they were put there by mistake.)

The way you wrote the command, it runs `cmd.exe` with the initial command `cd D:/Jhipster/myapp`, then, only after exiting from `cmd`, runs `yo`.

P.S. You may want to `cd /d D:/Jhipster/myapp`. Without the `/d` it will change the current directory on drive D:, but won't necessarily make that drive current. Windows keeps a current directory for each drive.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.exe /K cd /d D:\Jhipster\myapp & yo jhipster:import-jdl D:\Jhipster\mindmaple\City.jh
```

A lot of basic syntax errors.